# Chrome Extension: get DOM before XSL transformation

Tags: javascript, dom, xslt, google-chrome-extension

i have a webpage containing this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="/some.xsl"?>
<OAI-PMH>
 <someTags/>
</OAI-PMH>
```

Chrome is doing the transformation by itself. (transformation in line 2)
If I look at the source of the page I find the original content, but chrome renders the xsl transformation output. (which is fine)

Now i want to access the root-tag of the page with something like this:

```
eventPage.js:

function getURL(details) {
console.log(document.documentElement.tagName);
}

chrome.webNavigation.onDOMContentLoaded.addListener(getURL);
```

with this function I get "HTML" als the root-tag of the DOM. Which is right *after* the transformation but i want the root-tag *before* the transformation. (in this case: OAI-PMH)

I don't find the right listener ;)
can someone lead me to the right place?

```
manifest.json:
...
"background": {
 "scripts": ["eventPage.js"],
 "persistent": false
},
...
```

thx

Comment: Perform a new request, use `DOMParser` to generate the tree and have fun.

Comment: sry, but what do you mean with "Perform a new request" ?

Comment: Retrieve the page's source code using `XMLHttpRequest`. You can skip the `DOMParser` part by reading the `responseXML` property.

Comment: ok thx...this should work. As a workaround it's ok but it doesn't seem clean to me. Chrome already downloaded the page and now i have to download it again? thanks anyway!